# Progressbar for a XMLHttpRequest file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlhttprequest

Firstly sorry if it was a potential duplicate for this issue.

I am trying to display the file download status and display it in the dialog box using XMLHttprequest. So far I am able to achieve in displaying the download status in a dialog but once the file is downloaded. the file was not created but stored in the browser memory. I am able to see the file is downloaded in the response of my request.

Can anyone please help me how can i show the progress without overwriting the file download behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be tracking XMLHttpRequest's [progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) which you can then use to update the dialog:

```
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentLoaded = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        console.log(percentLoaded);
    }
});
```

(One caveat: while this is supported in all modern browsers it is not supported below IE10.)

Comment: i am using the above event to display the progress but problem for me is the file  received is not creating on the browser. do i need to perform any actions in onload after readystate is 4 to create a file on the browser and to save it.